# Show subcategories only for selected category page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to show subcategories only for the category page which is being viewed. I have a lot of categories and all of them have their subcategories, but I don't want to show them on main page. I want to show subcategories only for that category page in sidebar. Is it possible?

please suggest

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$parent_term_id = 4 // term id of parent term

$taxonomies = array( 
    'category',
);

$args = array(
    'parent'         => $parent_term_id,
    // 'child_of'      => $parent_term_id, 
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```